# why fragment can't hide bottom bar

Tags: android, fragment, navigationbar

why fragment can't hide bottom bar

but activity can hide top and bottom

use the following code :

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);     
getActionBar().hide();
```

### fragment side didn't work

**i try answer 1 
but it still not work
when i touch my fragment area 
it will show top and bottom ,let me confused a lot**

following is my code:
(fragment side)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

  View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
  int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION|View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
  decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);    
  getActivity().getActionBar().hide();
} 

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ge, container, false);
   return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Thank Simple Plan can reply me

Comment: did you found any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Ofcourse you can hide the bottom navigation bar.
Here is my recycler scroll listener in my fragment. `blogWriteBtn` is my `Floatingactionbutton`, don't worry about that.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (dy > 0 && blogWriteBtn.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                blogWriteBtn.hide();
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).SetNavigationVisibiltity(false);
            } else if (dy < 0 && blogWriteBtn.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                blogWriteBtn.show();
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).SetNavigationVisibiltity(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

and in my `MainActivity` which has bottom navigation bar. I have added this method..

```
public void SetNavigationVisibiltity (boolean b) {
    if (b) {
        bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

It worked perfectly fine for me. Here we called the public method `SetNavigationVisibilty(boolean)` of `MainActivity`. We can do like this.

Answer (score 0):

Chuang, try `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY` instead of the other two flags that you have used. This was introduced in API 19 as per my knowledge and will require you to have the minimum SDK version to be same.